# Forward client header, isp, geo to the server via proxy

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

My website has the proxy server created using express nodejs with nginx. The problem I am having, and cant seem to figure out is that I want to forward all the original users details and not show any proxy server details to the final destination server.

Scheme:
User -> my website -> proxy server -> final server to retrieve the data.

Now, no matter what configs I change in nginx, seems like the final server always identifies my proxy server isp, geo etc and not the users isp. If I access the final server directly without the proxy, the final server will show users isp.

How do I make sure that the proxy server is not being detected as "original" requester to the final server?

Some code for better understanding:

Nginx proxy:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x.x;
        include    proxy.conf;
    }
```

nginxconfig:

```
proxy_http_version                 1.1;
proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

# Proxy headers
proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host              $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
```

Requests inside the node (to call final server) made like this (just a sample):

```
app.post('/getStats', (req, res) => {
      const url = request('url')
      req.pipe(url).pipe(res)
})
```

Comment: The destination web server will always see the request from the IP address of your server/proxy server, so isn't guaranteed to get any client information. Can you include the request headers from the incoming request to node? And the headers after it has traversed the proxy? The proxy could be overwriting one of those, or the final server is trusting "X-Real-IP"